# Software to proxy socket connections across a TTY-like link

Tags: unix, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm looking for some software that can perform remote forwarding of socket connections across a TTY-style link.  I have two machines, A and B.  I have admin privileges on A, but not B, but on machine B I am able to run arbitrary server software that does not require admin.  Machine A does not have a public IP address, but machine B does.  I am able to set up an outgoing connection from machine A to machine B and transfer arbitrary data across it, but what I need is some software that I can run on machine B that will accept an incoming connection, send the data from that connection to a process running on machine A, which will then initiate a new connection to a server running on machine A.

I am, unfortunately, not able to use ssh for this purpose as it has been configured by the administrator of machine B not to allow forwarding.  Otherwise, running `ssh -R 4567:localhost:1234 machineb` from machine A would achieve what I'm looking for.

Anyone know of another way of doing this?  For reference, machine A runs Ubuntu Linux and machine B runs OpenBSD, although I'd prefer a solution portable across all unix variants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat2.html) to do the job. You need `socat` installed on machine A and `nc` (`netcat`) on machine B (`socat` will also work). Following there's an example on how to handle **one TCP connection** (you can read [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html)'s documentation to know how to handle more and customize behaviour).

You should run on machine A:

- The service you want to expose to machine B, let's say a webserver on port 8000 (you can test it by running `python3 -m http.server` or `python2 -m SimpleHTTPServer` in any directory you want to expose the files);
- [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat2.html) to redirect between STDIO and an SSH connection to B. This SSH connection to B will run `nc` listening to a specific port.

So, run on one terminal session on machine A:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

And in another terminal session on machine A:

```
socat EXEC:'ssh user@machineb "nc -l -p 8888"' TCP4:localhost:8000
```

If `socat` is also available on machine B, you can replace `nc` with it:

```
socat EXEC:'ssh user@machineb "socat STDIO TCP-LISTEN:8888,reuseaddr"' TCP4:localhost:8000
```

Explaining the concept: `socat` will redirect any stdin/stdout of the command `ssh user@machineb "socat STDIO TCP-LISTEN:8888,reuseaddr"` to a TCP client connection on `localhost:8000` (`TCP4:localhost:8000`). The command will run the SSH connection to machine B and run `socat` there, which will redirect anything that connects to port 8888 locally on machine B (`TCP-LISTEN:8888,reuseaddr`) to the stdin/stdout (`STDIO`).

Yes, [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat2.html) is awesome!